# How to make sklearn.TfidfVectorizer tokenize special phrases?

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, tokenize, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to create a tf-idf table using `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn` package in python. For example I have a corpus of one string
`"PD-L1 expression positive (≥1%–49%) and negative for actionable molecular markers"`

`TfidfVectorizer` has an `token_pattern` argument that indicates how the token should be like.
The default is `token_pattern = token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`, it will split all the words by space and remove the numbers and special characters to create the tokens, and generates some tokens like below

[`"pd", "expression", "positive","and" ,"negative" ,"for" ,"actionable" ,"molecular" ",markers"]`

But something I would like to have is:

`["pd-l1", "expression", "positive", "≥1%–49%","and" ,"negative" ,"for" ,"actionable" "molecular" ,"markers"]`

I was tweaking `token_pattern` argument for hours but cannot get it right. Alternatively, Is there here a way to tell explicitly to the vectorizer that I want to have`pd-l1` and `>1%-49%` as token without going too wild on regrex? Any help is
very appreciated!

Comment: you should show what `token_pattern` did you try to use.

Comment: with normal module `re` I can split it with `token_pattern='[^ ()]+'` (all chars except `space`,`(`,`)`) in `re.findall(token_pattern, text)` but `TfidfVectorizer` may use pattern in different way.

Comment: Thanks! As indicated in this post, I used the default, tried to tweak it, but failed. Do I need to put all failed trials here?

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could copy and test ideas. And you could add trials to see what you already tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it using pattern `'[^ ()]+'` - all chars except `space`, `(`, `)`

It may need to add `punctuations` to this list.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

corpus = [
 "PD-L1 expression positive (≥1%–49%) and negative for actionable molecular markers"
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
print('token_pattern:', vectorizer.token_pattern)

vectorizer.token_pattern = '[^ ()]+'
print('token_pattern:', vectorizer.token_pattern)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Result

```
['actionable', 'and', 'expression', 'for', 'markers', 'molecular', 'negative', 'pd-l1', 'positive', '≥1%–49%']
```

---

I used example code from documetation [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

---

**EDIT:**

I checked documentation and I could set it directly

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='[^ ()]+')
```